# Exclude files in jscs vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jscs

There is a `.jscsrc` file in the root directory of the project and it has settings set by other people and I want to add my own options but only on my own vscode. Like excluding `gulpfile.js`.

I currently have the snippet below in my settings.

```
"jscs.configuration": {
    "excludeFiles": ["gulpfile.js"]
}
```

But it still shows indention errors from `gulpfile.js`. And I do not want to touch settings that are shared.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the current version (0.2.0 at the moment) of the vscode jscs plugin.
Here are more details of this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-jscs/issues/8